# How to close "open files" in TexMaker

Tags: errors, texmaker, windows, viewers

When I finish building a PDF in TexMaker, I close the `.tex` file from which it was generated and clear the PDFViewer. I then try to move or delete the newly created PDF but receive an Windows error saying "The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program". None of the files I'm moving are open in TexMaker, nor are they displayed in the PDFViewer. I can close TexMaker then move or delete files just fine, but this is incredibly annoying when I'm working on many files at once.

Does TexMaker have a cache or something I need to clear before moving things around? Why can't I move or delete previously generated PDFs with TexMaker still open?

I assure you, no files are open in the editor and the PDFViewer is not showing the PDF I'm trying to move or delete.